# Como Guardar registro de un button dentro de un foreach

Tags: array, botón, tablas, foreach, where

Buen día, tengo una duda para un programa que estoy desarrollando, soy nuevo en php y no soy muy bueno dándome a entender así que me disculpan por favor si no se me comprende perfectamente.

Tengo un registro de médicos en SQL el cual mi programa de php va, lo consulta, y me lo trae en un array (creo...) la cosa es que con un foreach estoy plasmando mi tabla de médicos con número de colegiado línea por línea pero al final de cada una de estas lineas hay un button que a futuro se supone me permitirá consultar y editar detalladamente el médico por específico pero no se como hacer que cuando presione dicho button, el programa sepa a que médico me estoy refiriendo

espero haberme dado a entender y adjunto imagen de la tabla y el código para que me puedan apoyar, gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>COLEGIADO</b></td>
                        <td><b>NOMBRE</b></td>
                        <td><b>ACTIVO</b></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <?php foreach ($medicos_select as $Row_medicos) { ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td>  <?php echo $Row_medicos->Colegiado_medico ?>  </td>
                        <td>  <?php echo $Row_medicos->Nombre_medico ?>  </td>
                        <td>  <?php echo $Row_medicos->Activo_medico = 1 ? "SI": "NO";   ?>  </td>
                        <td><button type="submit" name="modify_medic" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">EDITAR</button></td>
                    </tr>

                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table><br><br>
```

Comment: La implementación exacta de la solución de tu problema depende de cómo lo quieras hacer. Porque podrías editar en la misma fila de la tabla, o podría ser que se abriera una ventana modal para editar o un link a otra página que tiene un formulario de edición. De cualquier manera lo que debes hacer es pasarle $Row_medicos->Colegiado_medico (que entiendo es el ID del médico) al botón

Comment: Muchas gracias, comprendo teóricamente lo que me propones pero no se como hacerlo.... como le asigno ese valor al boton??

y sobre ambas posibilidades pues se abrirá una nueva ventana para edición porque el colegiado y el nombre no es lo único con lo que cuenta el registro ya que cuenta con una dirección de correo, dirección regional, número de teléfono y otros apartados los cuales podrían en algún momento llegar a cambiar

Comment: he encontrado como jaja, gracias por tu ayuda ya me funcionó